# CSS Targeting Individual Paths through SVG -> Use tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, shadow-dom

I'm having huge problems animating an ellipsis icon to jiggle the little dots up and down in a wave. I suspect that because its in the shadow DOM I can't target the individual path elements specifically, however is there a work-around?

DOM looks like this:

```
<svg class="icon__vector">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-ellipsis"></use>
</svg>
```

Where the href link links to this SVG hardcoded in a sprite sheet in which I can edit if needed.

```
<svg id="icon-ellipsis" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path className="icon-ellipsis-dotone" d="M6 11.59c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2z"></path>
    <path className="icon-ellipsis-dottwo" d="M14 11.59c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2z"></path>
    <path className="icon-ellipsis-dotthree" d="M22 11.59c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2z"></path>
</svg>
```

EDIT:
So i have an ellipsis icon something like this "O O O" and i its loaded in with a `<use>` tag and i want to be able to target each individual dot and animate them differentely. I can edit the master sprite sheet, use javascript or css however no jquery.
Problem is that there is no way to target the individual paths because they exist in the shadow DOM

Comment: How do you animate it? (e.g. with jQuery)

Comment: i can target it through .icon__vector however that only lets me use simple stuff that cascades down like fill, 
i.e
.icon__vector {
     fill: red
}
however i want to target the individual paths and translateY(-5px) them on delays. I.E dotone translateY 0 delay, dottwo translateY 100ms delay, etc

Comment: willing to target through javascript or css, anything IE10+ compatible, however no jquery.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with CSS...

Use JS
 
Quick google results for possible approached gives: 
https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/ (looks good)
https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/ ( native approach) http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/javascript-libraries-animate-svg/ (list of js libraries)

Comment: thanks @AndreyMuzalevsky unfortunately, that first link doesn't use the "Use" tag which makes targetting to animate so difficult. the second link could be used to target and animate the entire svg, but it still can't be used to target individual paths within that svg. Finally i don't need a library this is a relatively simple animation to code out i just need a method of targetting the individual paths within my ellipsis

Comment: :-) may I propose you to use any other approach which will look the same way?

Comment: solved.
document.querySelector("#icon-ellipsis > path.icon-ellipsis-dotone")) as SVGPathElement;
lets you target the path with javascript

Comment: Hmm... your query actually looks quite obvious... the question now is what was initial query...

Comment: but using document.getElementsBy...... className or ID doesn't let you target the paths which is really wierd

Comment: Ah... Ok... Just FYI from my practice useful and often forgotten functions are: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CSS or JS to target the referenced elements **through** the `<use>`.

You can animate the targeted sprite directly.  However that means that, if the SVG is referenced more than once, all those instances will be animated at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any simple way to overcome this? Something like use+copy.

Comment: We just inlined the equivalent svg template and animated it.